# Can the Facebook graph API distinguish between share counts of website.com/?source=text vs. website.com/#fragment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example, I'd like to distinguish between shares of something like

`http://google.com` vs.
`http://google.com/#fragment` vs.
`http://google.com/?source=keyword`

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://google.com/#gizmodo&format=json or https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://google.com/?source=gizmodo&format=json versus shares of a straight-up https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://google.com/&format=json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can - assuming instead of www.google.com you are talking about a site that you control.  Also , assuming that by changing the querystring that is part of the url actually changes the page that the user sees.

The way that you would do this is to change the meta tags that are rendered in the HTML based on what the url is.  So if the user went to a page with url :

> http://www.myUrl.com

then the meta tags could be like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Workday Sets Price Range for I.P.O." />
<meta property="og:url" content="www.myUrl.com" />
// there are more then just these look up Facebook Docs
```

then when the user went to :

> http://www.myUrl.com?q=blah&a=blah

you would render different meta tags from your server, Facebook will read these and know they are supposed to be different pages

```
<meta property="og:title" content="DIffernt title here" />
<meta property="og:url" content="www.myUrl.com/blahhblooblah" />
// there are more then just these look up Facebook Docs
```

when you are done you should be using all these meta tags

- og:title
- og:site_name
- og:url
- og:description
- og:image
- fb:app_id